# WordPress - Login failure after migrating the site to AWS using All-in-one wp migration plugin

Tags: wordpress, migration

I migrated the 150MB WordPress site to AWS using All-in-one wp migration plugin, but once the migration is done the site is running good but I cannot log in to my WordPress "wp-admin" using neither with the new nor the old credentials. please help me out with this.

Comment: Do you have access to DB via phpmyadmin or similar software?

Comment: you should try again, also check if you have used advance option in all in one plugin which have option to edit tables i guess. but the password of exported site should work

Comment: No, @GrafiCodeStudio i don't have any acces to DB

Comment: @Manjunath I tried alot but it didn't workout

Comment: @vinay kumar if you have access to old wp site, use file manager plugin and navigate to root folder where wp-content etc will be there. So just find wp-config.php and check, i guess you will get wp db name and password. In AWS you have db access i guess where you can run commands. if you find this creds from wp-config.php you can gain access